# Icinga database cleanup

Tags: postgresql, nagios, nrpe, icinga

I am working in Icinga for performance data collection,

I have to clear all plugin data more than 30 days, how can I do this. I had some google searches does not help.

some references:

[External Commands List](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/appendix)

[Database model](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/db_model.html)

I am using:
RHEL os
icinga2 from source build
postgresql
Using NRPE for collecting remote server data

Is there any tool available to cleanup or any queries to delete all database entries older than 30 days?

Comment: There is a close request for this question as off topic, I don't find any stack-exchange with icinga tag? if so please let me know!!

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/configido.html#configido-ido2db

From the manual, it looks like your ido2db.cfg needs to be configured with the proper data:

```
max_systemcommands_age=43200
max_servicechecks_age=43200
max_hostchecks_age=43200
max_eventhandlers_age=43200
max_externalcommands_age=43200
max_logentries_age=43200
max_acknowledgements_age=43200
max_notifications_age=43200
max_contactnotifications_age=43200
max_contactnotificationmethods_age=43200
```

Also, make sure that `trim_db_interval` is set somewhat sane. The default of `3600` should be sufficient.

```
trim_db_interval=3600
```